# Whether a continuous function has fixed point or not when the domain and range are not $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, fixed-point-theorems

Which of the following is ***false*** $?$

$A.$ Any continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$  has a  fixed point.

$B.$ Any ***homeomorphism*** from $[0,1)$  to  $[0,1)$  has a fixed point.

$C.$ Any *bounded*  continuous  function  from  $[0,\infty)$ to  $[0,\infty)$  has a  fixed point .

$D.$ Any continuous function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ has a fixed point.

Now , if we take $f(x)=x^2$ , then $f((),1))\subset (0,1)$ but it does not show any fixed point. So, option $D$ is our  ***false*** statement .

And  option $A$  is  a  well  known  result .

So, turns  out  that , the  statements  in  option  $B$  and $C$  are  both  correct.  I need  help  to  prove  them.

For  $B$ , my thought  is  that  the  said  *homeomorphism*  can  be  extended  to  $[0,1]$ and  the  fixed   point  theorem  will  apply but  we  will  need  to  show  that  the  fixed  point  is  not  the  point  $x=1$.  Is  that right $?$ But  I  don't  know  $C$ .

Thanks  for   any  help.

Comment: Yes, the homeomorphism can be extended to $[0,1]$, but that requires proof. For another way, what property distinguishes $0$ from the other points in $[0,1)$? (Thus every _homeomorphism_ $[0,1) \to [0,1)$ must have $0$ as a fixed point. There _may_ be others, but $0$ _must_ be one.) For C, you could think about how the intermediate value theorem relates to the situation.

Comment: A only is true if the function is surjective to me, maybe Im wrong.

Comment: Dear @Masacroso,A is always true. Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and use Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: For part C, you can restrict the function from $[0,M]$ to $[0,M]$ where $M$ is an upper bound of the range.

Answer (score 1):

For B consider that $0$ is the only point $p\in [0,1)$ such that $[0,1)\backslash \{p\}$ is a connected space, so a homeomorphism $f$ must have $f(0)=0.$ Another way is that $B=\{[0,d):0<d<1\}$ is a neighborhood base at $ 0$ such that $\forall b\in B\; (\bar b\backslash b$   has just one member.) No other point in $[0,1)$ has a nbhd base with this property, so $f(0)=0$.....For C if $f(0)=0$ we are done. If $f(0)>0$ the continuous function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is positive at $x=0$ and negative when $x>\sup \{f(y) :y\geq 0\}$ so for some $x$ we have $ g(x)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT. The same proof based on the intermediate value theorem that you use to prove A works for D too. You don't even need $f$ to be bounded; any less-than-linear bound $f(x)\le Cx^\alpha,\ 0< \alpha < 1$ will suffice.